# Codeigniter 4 - How to store User data after logging in using cookies and AJAX

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, setcookie, codeigniter-4

I am still learning CodeIgniter 4 and this is the first time I encountered cookies.

*Describing my case below:*

I want to save user data (*email* and *password*) after a user logs in to a page using cookies.

The first page is Login, after a user logs in, it brings him to the *Dashboard* page.

If the user clicks the "*log out*" link, it will destroy cookies and redirect to the login page.

If the user does not click the logout button, the next time he comes back to the login page, it will use the user data saved before to log in automatically and bring him to the "*dashboard*" page.

My `students` table includes 3 columns: `id`, `email`, `password`.

**My cookie_login View**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cookie Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>/public/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@bootstrapstudio/bootstrap-better-nav/dist/bootstrap-better-nav.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>/public/assets/css/Navigation-with-Button.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>/public/assets/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>/public/assets/css/styles-v6.2.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>/public/assets/css/emojionearea.min.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Animate -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
        <!-- NEW - CSS Chat -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jQuery CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/css/alertify.min.css" integrity="sha512-IXuoq1aFd2wXs4NqGskwX2Vb+I8UJ+tGJEu/Dc0zwLNKeQ7CW3Sr6v0yU3z5OQWe3eScVIkER4J9L7byrgR/fA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js" integrity="sha512-JnjG+Wt53GspUQXQhc+c4j8SBERsgJAoHeehagKHlxQN+MtCCmFDghX9/AcbkkNRZptyZU4zC8utK59M5L45Iw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div style="width: 60%; display:inline-block; padding-top: 50px;">
                <h1>Login Form with Cookie</h1>
                <div class="form-group my-2">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                  <span class="text-danger email_error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group my-2">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                  <span class="text-danger password_error"></span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            $(document).on('click','#login',function(){
                email = $('#email').val();
                password = $('#password').val();
                
                if(email.length === 0)
                {
                    $('.email_error').append('<p>Enter your email.</p>');
                }
                
                if(password.length === 0)
                {
                    $('.password_error').append('<p>Enter your password.</p>');
                }
                
                if(email.length !== 0 && password.length !== 0)
                {
                    var base_url = "<?= base_url(); ?>";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: base_url + "/testcookies/login",
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {'email': email, 'password': password},
                        beforeSend: function(){
                           $('#login').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                       },
                        success: function(response){
                            $('#login').attr('disabled', false);
                            if(response.status === 'success')
                            {
                                window.location.replace("<?= base_url(); ?>/cookiedashboard/");
                            }
                        }
                     });
                     return false;
                }
                
            });
            
            
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**My cookie_dashboard view:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cookie Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div style="width: 60%; display:inline-block; padding-top: 30px;">
                <h1>Cookie Dashboard</h1>
                <a href="<?= base_url(); ?>/testcookies/logout/">Log Out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

**TestCookies Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\CookiesModel;

class TestCookies extends BaseController {
    
    public $cookieModel;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->cookieModel = new \App\Models\CookiesModel();
        helper('cookie');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(get_cookie('email') && get_cookie('password'))
        {
            $email = get_cookie('email');
            $password = get_cookie('password');
            
            if($this->cookieModel->login($email, $password))
            {
                return redirect()->to(base_url().'/cookiedashboard/')->withCookies();
            }
        }
        
        return view('cookie_login');
    }
        
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->request->isAJAX())
        {
            $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
            $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
            
            if($this->cookieModel->login($email, $password))
            {
                set_cookie('email', $email,300);
                set_cookie('password', $password,300);
                $data['status'] = 'success';
                return $this->response->setJSON($data);
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    

    public function logout() 
    {
        delete_cookie('email');
        delete_cookie('password');
        return redirect()->to(base_url().'/testcookies/');
    }
}
```

**CookieDashboard Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\CookiesModel;

class CookieDashboard extends BaseController {

    public $cookieModel;
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->cookieModel = new \App\Models\CookiesModel();
        helper('cookie');
    }
    
    public function index()
    {
        if(empty(get_cookie('email')) && empty(get_cookie('password')))
        {
            return redirect()->to(base_url().'/testcookies/');
        }
        return view('cookie_dashboard');
    }
    
    
}
```

**CookiesModel Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class CookiesModel extends Model {
    
    public function login($email,$password)
    {
        $builder = $this->db->table('students');
        $builder->where('email',$email);
        $builder->where('password',$password);
        $result = $builder->get();
        
        if(count($result->getResultArray()) == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public function studentData($email) {
        
        $builder = $this->db->table('students');
        $builder->where('email',$email);
        $result = $builder->get();
        
        if(count($result->getResultArray()) == 1)
        {
            return $result->getRowArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

In the path: **app\Config\Cookie.php**, the file I set below:

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use DateTimeInterface;

class Cookie extends BaseConfig
{

    public $prefix = '';

    public $expires = 300;

    public $path = '/';

    public $domain = 'localhost/';

    public $secure = false;

    public $httponly = true;

    public $samesite = 'Lax';

    public $raw = false;
}
```

In this form, I just want to learn cookies so I put very simple HTML code.
The form worked well with AJAX login until I added Cookie lines.
I put the expiration time as `300` aiming to test the cookie after `5` minutes.

So please help me with basic information about cookies and how to use it in Codeigniter 4. I have read a few times from [Codeigniter 4 helper](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html) and [library reference](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cookies.html) and it seems I could not go through them. I also studied many posts in Stack overflow but they are not helpful as some of them are applied for older versions and the rest I tried but not working.

Most importantly, please help me correct the above source code to make the HTML forms work.

Comment: _"I want to save user data (email and password) after a user logs in to a page using Cookie"_ - No, you really don't. The contents of a cookie are stored as text in the users browser. Anyone with access to that computer/browser will be able to read those cookies and thus find their password. Basically, don't store sensitive information in the client. If you want to build a "remember me" function, search specifically for that and you should find some more secure ways for it.

Comment: **Warning!** Never store passwords in your database (or anywhere, really) in plain text! You should only store password hashes generated using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and to verify a password againts a hash, use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [M.Eriksson in a comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/132947650?noredirect=1)

> **Warning!** Never store passwords in your database (or anywhere, really) in plain text! You should only store password hashes generated
> using
> [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
> and to verify a password against a hash, use
> [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

I would suggest that you make use of tested, secure and well-maintained libraries/frameworks instead of reinventing the wheel. A couple of solutions already exist to handle all this for you. I.e:

[CodeIgniter Shield](https://github.com/codeigniter4/shield#codeigniter-shield)

> Shield is an authentication and authorization framework for
> CodeIgniter 4. While it does provide a base set of tools that are
> commonly used in websites, it is designed to be flexible and easily
> customizable.

[Shield: An Official Auth Library for CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/news/shield)

> Among the many features that Shield ships with are:
>
> - Session-based authentication (traditional email/password with remember me)
> - Stateless authentication using Personal Access Tokens
> - Optional Email verification on account registration
> - Optional Email-based Two Factor Authentication after login
> - Magic Login Links when a user forgets their password
> - Flexible groups-based access control (think roles, but more flexible)
> - Users can be granted additional permissions
> - User Entity and UserModel ready for you to use or extend
> - A simple helper that provides access to the most common auth actions
> - Easily extendable controllers
> - All required views that can be used as is or swapped out for your own
> - Highly configurable
> - Built to extend and modify
> - Save initial settings in your code so it can be in version control, but can also be updated in the database, thanks to our [Settings
>   library](https://github.com/codeigniter4/settings)

##### Resource

Please read:

[Shield Documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/shield/)

Comment: Thank you so much Steven!
I'll have look at the links you shared.